# Make mathematica workspace variables accessible inside a function without using function arguments

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a Mathematica function that calls NotebookEvaluate, but the notebook being evaluated needs variables defined in the workspace of the notebook from which the function is defined and called. How can I make the variables defined in the notebook that calls the function available to the notebook being evaluated by NotebookEvaluate?

Thanks in advance,
Ed Hall

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't be a problem accessing variables from outside the evaluation notebook, for example below.

```
Clear[x]
x = 2;
nb = CreateDocument[ExpressionCell[Defer[x^2], "Input"]];
NotebookEvaluate[nb]
x = 3;
NotebookEvaluate[nb]
```

> 4

> 9